# Modular Design affects compilation time

Tags: compiler, c++11, modularization

Does modular design decrease compilation time in cpp? My professor said so, but I don't understand how, because the build and compilation time depend on the amount of code, right?

Also, wouldn't resolution of header guards in a separate module and stuff like that actually increase the compile time (marginally as I understand that the extra time taken would be negligible as a computer can perform operations super fast.)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of. The tricky part is the role of header files.

The C/C++ compilation model handles one "compilation unit" at a time. Roughly, there is one compilation unit per `.cpp` file. Different compilation units can be compiled concurrently, but the resulting "object code" is then linked into the final executable or library.

Using multiple compilation units instead of one large compilation unit can make compiles faster because (a) more stuff can be done in parallel, and (b) when making changes and recompiling, only the changed compilation units have to be actually recompiled. This can greatly accelerate the edit–test–debug cycle.

Header files describe interfaces and are included into *multiple* compilation units. There are two consequences for this:

- Code in the headers is compiled *multiple times*, once for each compilation unit that includes the header. In C, headers don't tend to include much code like inline functions, but in C++ this is different. Headers include class definitions, potentially with inline methods. Headers might include templates, which are instantiated and compiled separately in each compilation unit, though the linker might later remove duplicates. All of this is great for code optimization opportunities, but it means the compiler does a lot of duplicate work.
- When you edit a header in a way that changes the "ABI" (memory layout or function signatures), then you must recompile all compilation units that include this header. A small change in one header file can make it necessary to recompile an entire project, which is pretty painful on large-scale projects that might need 40 minutes for a clean compile.

So, there is interest in techniques that help to isolate compilation units from each other, so that we have to include less details in the header files, and can make changes without large-scale recompiles while working on a project.

Many OOP design patterns provide exactly this. By writing code that only depends on an interface (in the OOP sense), we can hide implementation details from that code, making it easier to evolve the codebase. It also helps with compile times. But since this introduces pointer indirection and virtual methods and prevents optimizations like inlining, there's a small runtime performance penalty for such techniques.

A C++-spefic pattern is "pImpl". A non-OOP technique that works in both C and C++ is to use forward definitions for types without fully defining them in the headers, which encapsulates the struct's layout.

Header guards are not that relevant here. Evaluating preprocessor directives is incredibly cheap compared to anything else the compiler does. It also reduces the amount of work the compiler has to do. More importantly, header guards might be necessary to honour the *one definition rule* (ODR).

C++ has recently introduced a concept of "modules" that makes header files unnecessary, avoiding duplicate work and thus potentially speeding up compiles. However as of 2023, compiler support is still lacking, and the library ecosystem continues to expect headers. Other (younger) languages like Java or Rust have compilation models that work without headers, though techniques for decoupling compilation units still remain relevant.

Answer (score 2):

As the build process for the entire system becomes more complex, it's likely to take a bit longer.

BUT as you don't need to rebuild the entire system on each and every code change, just the module that changes, the build time per trigger evening for your build is likely to decrease.